# How can i make a different oath flow between login & signup for social? like google oauth2.0 using passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I want the Auth0 to distinguish between social signup and social login.
If a new user tries to log in with social before signing up, AUTH0 should response with Error and will ask the user to signup first.
Today, when a user logs in with Social without signing up, AUTH0 treats it as signup.

```
exports.google_LogIn = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Passport strategy allows you to return with a user or an error.

For example this Google strategy will return an error if your database hasn't already seen the user before (using [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)).

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         if (!user) return done(Error("needs signup"), null)
         return done(err, user)
       });
  }
));
```

In the callback route you can then give Passport a `failureRedirect` to send the user to your signup page when there is an error.

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/signUpPage' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```